# sql insert multiple rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have tables:

`ContainerSubTypes (Id, Name)` with many records,

`WorkAreas (Id, Name)` with only one row,

`WorkAreaContainerSubTypes table (Id, WorkAreaId, ContainerSubTypeId)` - empty table.

I need to insert data into `WorkAreaContainerSubTypes` table, it should look like:

```
(1, 1, containersubtype1_id)
(2, 1, containersubtype2_id)
(3, 1, containersubtype3_id)
```

And I'm trying sql like:

```
INSERT INTO WorkAreaContainerSubTypes (WorkAreaId, ContainerSubTypeId)
    VALUES
    (1, (SELECT Id FROM ContainerSubTypes));
```

But `SELECT` query has more than 1 row and it throws error.
How can I implement that inserting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table value constructor specifies *a set of row value expressions to be constructed into a table*, so you need a different statement:

```
INSERT INTO WorkAreaContainerSubTypes (WorkAreaId, ContainerSubTypeId)
SELECT 1, Id 
FROM ContainerSubTypes;
```

As an additional note, you may use `VALUES` only if `SELECT Id FROM ContainerSubTypes` statement returns a single row or no rows (perhaps with an optional `WHERE` clause):

```
INSERT INTO WorkAreaContainerSubTypes (WorkAreaId, ContainerSubTypeId)
VALUES
   (1, (SELECT Id FROM ContainerSubTypes WHERE Name = 'Some name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO WorkAreaContainerSubTypes (WorkAreaId, ContainerSubTypeId)
    SELECT 1, Id
    FROM ContainerSubTypes;
```